# htaccess mod_rewrite not detects params for project

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wamp

I started a php project based on http://www.php-mvc.net/ and i searched on Google how to set up my `WAMP Server` to enable `URL` rewriting.

I'm running the latest version of WAMP.

1) Enable `mod_rewrite` module on `httpd.conf`

2) On `httpd-vhosts.conf` i added a virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName phpmvc.test
ServerAlias *.phpmvc.test
VirtualDocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\phpmvc"
ErrorLog "logs\errors.log"
<directory "C:\wamp\www\phpmvc">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from all
</directory>
```

3) On my hosts file i added the host `127.0.0.1 phpmvc.test`

4) On .htacces file i have this lines

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I restarted Apache after setting up the files and when i went to `phpmvc.test` it worked fine but when i tried `phpmvc.test/test` it shows an error that says that the requested URL is not found on this server.

EDIT: I tried with `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]` but it shows the same error
EDIT2: I tried with EDIT: I tried with Rahil Wazir suggestion but it stills not working.

I have this controller file `IndexController.class.php` and it works if i access with this URL: `phpmvc.test?url=index` but if i try `phpmvc.test/index` it says that `index` is not found on the server.

```
<?php

class IndexController {

    public static function index() {

        echo "Index controller";

    }
}
```

Printing `$_GET` and `$_SERVER` on root i get an empty `Array()` and the server array. If i go to `phpmvc.test/index?url=index` i get the value on `$_GET["url"]` and on `$_SERVER [QUERY_STRING] => url=index`.

Comment: Your RewriteRule depends on a trailing `/` slash for incoming paths.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Apache thinks `/test` is a file or directory which you are trying to accessing which probably don't exist.

You need to apply those two famous condition which is used by most [Front controller pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) frameworks:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Which tells Apache Rewrite Module unless the file or directory from the requested uri is exist then apply the rewrite rule, otherwise render the contents of the file or directory.

Comment: i added the lines that you said me but the error remains there :/

Answer (score 0):

Debug by checking what you are getting in $_GET and $_SERVER variables.

```
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_SERVER);
```

Compare the differences in the values for ['url'] index.
Also, it may depend on your sub-folder depth as seen on the URL before /index.

Comment: i added the info that you told me